# use awk inside an alias

Tags: bash, bashrc, alias

I have this awk command to increment a number inside a file:

```
awk -F"." '{$4=$4<=99?$4+1:0;print}' OFS="." post_all/version.ini > tmp && mv tmp post_all/version.ini
```

This works fine from bash, but when I try to add it to my bashrc it fails...

I tried adding `alias update_version=awk -F"." '{$4=$4<=99?$4+1:0;print}' OFS="." post_all/version.ini > tmp && mv tmp post_all/version.ini`

and the errors I got were:

```
-bash: =99?+1:0: No such file or directory
-bash: print} OFS="." post_all/version.ini > tmp && mv tmp post_all/version.ini: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The alias value should be a single string. Also, it's better to use a function unless you like pulling out your hair trying to figure out the quoting required.

Comment: I changed the `'` into `"` but now I get awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =. How would I change this into a good function?

Comment: `update_version () { awk -F"." '{$4=$4<=99?$4+1:0;print}' OFS="." post_all/version.ini > tmp && mv tmp post_all/version.ini; }`

Comment: Same error `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =`